# Problems replacing grouped patterns with PHP regex

Tags: php, json, regex

I have a JSON file that I want to use PHP to replace the "Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs" value from a string to an array. "39122" becomes [39122] and "39223, 39244, 39395" becomes [39223, 39244, 39395].  I am using http://www.regexpal.com/ to test my expression.  The expression is:

```
"([(0-9)+((, *))]+)+"
```

This is producing unexpected results in PHP.  In my JSON file:

```
[{
        "ID": 1050436,
        "Title": "THE SKY IS FALLING!!!!",
        "Application_x0020_ID": 242,
        "Systems_x0020_Changed": "Academic Planning System (APS),\"Documents planning and evaluation processes at UGA that support cont",
        "Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs": "39122",
        "Status": "New",
        "Modified": "2015-10-28T16:14:45.573-04:00",
        "Age": 40,
        "Description_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "I'm chicken little and the SKY IS FALLING!",
        "Impact_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "The world is going to end!",
        "Start_x0020_Time": "2015-10-28T00:00:00-04:00",
        "End_x0020_Time": "2015-10-30T00:00:00-04:00",
        "Hours": 12
    }, {
        "ID": 1050740,
        "Title": "This is a Title",
        "Application_x0020_ID": 242,
        "Systems_x0020_Changed": "EITS Websites,\"EITS departmental web pages.\", GACRC Archival Storage,\"Archival Storage for Research Data\", VPS,\"Mainframe distributed printing system\"",
        "Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs": "39223, 39244, 39395",
        "Status": "New",
        "Modified": "2015-11-05T17:31:13.15-05:00",
        "Age": 32,
        "Description_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "We will tell jokes to the clients",
        "Impact_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "Everyone will notice the change.",
        "Start_x0020_Time": "2015-11-27T08:38:00-05:00",
        "End_x0020_Time": "2015-11-30T00:00:00-05:00",
        "Hours": 1
    }]
```

Several commas at the end of lines are being replaced with brackets[] so that the output looks like:

```
[{
    "ID": 1050436,
    "Title": "THE SKY IS FALLING!!!![,]Application_x0020_ID": 242,
    "Systems_x0020_Changed": "Academic Planning System (APS),\"Documents planning and evaluation processes at UGA that support cont[,]Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs": 39122,
    "Status": "New[,]Modified": "2015-10-28T16:14:45.573-04:00[,]Age": 40,
    "Description_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "I'm chicken little and the SKY IS FALLING![,]Impact_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "The world is going to end![,]Start_x0020_Time": "2015-10-28T00:00:00-04:00[,]End_x0020_Time": "2015-10-30T00:00:00-04:00[,]Hours": 12
}, {
    "ID": 1050740,
    "Title": "This is a Title[,]Application_x0020_ID": 242,
    "Systems_x0020_Changed": "EITS Websites,\"EITS departmental web pages.\", GACRC Archival Storage,\"Archival Storage for Research Data\", VPS,\"Mainframe distributed printing system\"[,]Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs": [39223, 39244, 39395],
    "Status": "New[,]Modified": "2015-11-05T17:31:13.15-05:00[,]Age": 32,
    "Description_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "We will tell jokes to the clients[,]Impact_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "Everyone will notice the change.[,]Start_x0020_Time": "2015-11-27T08:38:00-05:00[,]End_x0020_Time": "2015-11-30T00:00:00-05:00[,]Hours": 1
}]
```

My question is, how can I modify the expression so that PHP will behave like regexpal.com and only get the numbers within quotes and ignore the rest?

Comment: Modifying structured data like JSON with regexes is asking for trouble.  I suggest reading it into a proper structure with `json_decode`, modifying the structure, and writing it back out with `json_encode`.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is rather strange, you appear to be trying to put a pattern expression inside a character class `[...]`, which is probably not doing what you'd expect.  Furthermore, your regex would match values inside other key/value pairs.  Try this instead, which will only match values for the key "Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs":

```
"Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs":\s+"([^"]*)"
```

Comment: @miken32 `\d+` will fail on `"Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs": "39223, 39244, 39395"`

Comment: @miken32 - That might be true, but the post certainly doesn't say anything about wanting to match only digits, so I didn't make any assumption about what is in the field.

Answer (score 1):

What about just parsing it as the JSON that it is?

```
$jsons = array('{
        "ID": 1050436,
        "Title": "THE SKY IS FALLING!!!!",
        "Application_x0020_ID": 242,
        "Systems_x0020_Changed": "Academic Planning System (APS),\"Documents planning and evaluation processes at UGA that support cont",
        "Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs": "39122",
        "Status": "New",
        "Modified": "2015-10-28T16:14:45.573-04:00",
        "Age": 40,
        "Description_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "I\'m chicken little and the SKY IS FALLING!",
        "Impact_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "The world is going to end!",
        "Start_x0020_Time": "2015-10-28T00:00:00-04:00",
        "End_x0020_Time": "2015-10-30T00:00:00-04:00",
        "Hours": 12
    }', '{
        "ID": 1050740,
        "Title": "This is a Title",
        "Application_x0020_ID": 242,
        "Systems_x0020_Changed": "EITS Websites,\"EITS departmental web pages.\", GACRC Archival Storage,\"Archival Storage for Research Data\", VPS,\"Mainframe distributed printing system\"",
        "Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs": "39223, 39244, 39395",
        "Status": "New",
        "Modified": "2015-11-05T17:31:13.15-05:00",
        "Age": 32,
        "Description_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "We will tell jokes to the clients",
        "Impact_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "Everyone will notice the change.",
        "Start_x0020_Time": "2015-11-27T08:38:00-05:00",
        "End_x0020_Time": "2015-11-30T00:00:00-05:00",
        "Hours": 1
    }');
foreach($jsons as $json){
     $json_array = json_decode($json, true);
     echo $json_array['Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs'] . "\n";
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/481865

If you needed a regex you could do something like:

```
"Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs":\h*"(([\d+],?\h*)*)"
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yZ6eM3/1

PHP Usage:

```
$string = '{
        "ID": 1050436,
        "Title": "THE SKY IS FALLING!!!!",
        "Application_x0020_ID": 242,
        "Systems_x0020_Changed": "Academic Planning System (APS),\"Documents planning and evaluation processes at UGA that support cont",
        "Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs": "39122",
        "Status": "New",
        "Modified": "2015-10-28T16:14:45.573-04:00",
        "Age": 40,
        "Description_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "I\'m chicken little and the SKY IS FALLING!",
        "Impact_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "The world is going to end!",
        "Start_x0020_Time": "2015-10-28T00:00:00-04:00",
        "End_x0020_Time": "2015-10-30T00:00:00-04:00",
        "Hours": 12
    }, {
        "ID": 1050740,
        "Title": "This is a Title",
        "Application_x0020_ID": 242,
        "Systems_x0020_Changed": "EITS Websites,\"EITS departmental web pages.\", GACRC Archival Storage,\"Archival Storage for Research Data\", VPS,\"Mainframe distributed printing system\"",
        "Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs": "39223, 39244, 39395",
        "Status": "New",
        "Modified": "2015-11-05T17:31:13.15-05:00",
        "Age": 32,
        "Description_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "We will tell jokes to the clients",
        "Impact_x0020__x0028_Public_x0029_": "Everyone will notice the change.",
        "Start_x0020_Time": "2015-11-27T08:38:00-05:00",
        "End_x0020_Time": "2015-11-30T00:00:00-05:00",
        "Hours": 1
    }';
$regex = '/"Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs":\h*"((?:[\d+],?\h*)*)"/';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 39122
    [1] => 39223, 39244, 39395
)
```

Demo #2: https://eval.in/481871

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for is:

```
$str = preg_replace('/"((\d+[, ]*)+)"/', "[$1]", $str);
```

I needed the JSON file as is except for number values as strings.  My regex worked after I played with it a little more.

Comment: Isn't that the regex I gave in the second part of my answer, just less strict? `(([\d+],?\h*)*)`

Comment: It may be. I didn't even pay attention because you added Systems_x0020_Changed_IDs to the front of it, which is not something I wanted to do.  But thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Now that I am looking at your regex, I see that it may be a better solution.  Thanks for the help!